# Connect equation boxes in beamer

Tags: amsmath, boxes, empheq

I am looking for the simplest way to connect two equation boxes with an arrow. Currently I am using the `empheq`. This is what I have done so far:

```
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\mymath}[1][]{%
    nobeforeafter, math upper, tcbox raise base,
    enhanced, sharp corners, colback=white!10, colframe=red!30!black, boxrule=2pt}

\begin{empheq}[box={%
       \mymath[colback=red!30,drop lifted shadow, sharp corners]}]{equation*}
       \color{black} \mathrm{x^2+x+3=1}
    \end{empheq}
    \begin{empheq}[box={%
       \mymath[colback=red!30,drop lifted shadow, sharp corners]}]{equation*}
       \color{black} \mathrm{x^2+x+2=0}
    \end{empheq}
```

And I got this:

[image]

I want that boxes look like this:

[image]

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: you are probably more likely to get help if you provide a full minimal example instead of just a snippet

Answer (score 4):

Note that in the absence of a working example, I decided to provide something that does not make use of `empheq` or `tcolorbox`. The former is likely to be easy to add afterwards, and the latter seemed overkill just for those rectangles.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}   

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw}, very thick]
    \node (a) at (0, 2) {$x^2 + x + 3 = 1$};
    \node (b) at (0, 0) {$x^2 + x + 2 = 0$};
    \draw[->] (a) to (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really wish to use `tcolorboxes` and stuff, you should be able to put them in the nodes. Remove the `draw` option from the nodes' style to avoid having a double rectangle, then.